# Regular Expresion in python does not match in non-greedy in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string pattern:

`"(https?://finance\.sina\.com\.cn/.+?shtml)"`

and I use `findall` method of `re` to match a content, but the result contains:

`'http://finance.sina.com.cn/nmetal/" target="_blank" style="margin-right:7px">黄金</a><a href="http://finance.sina.com.cn/futures/quotes/CL.shtml'`

and I have used non-greedy operators, but it still get wrong, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the first part of your regex:

```
https?://finance\.sina\.com\.cn/
```

matches the URL in the first `<a>` tag, and the second part

```
.+?shtml
```

then matches until it sees the `.sthml` in the second `<a>` tag because there is no `.shtml` on the first href. Ideally you should be using a DOM parser to parse HTML; then you couldn't run into this problem. In the interim, changing `.+?` into `[^"]+` so that part of the regex cannot go past the end of the current `href` will solve your problem. i.e.

```
(https?://finance\.sina\.com\.cn/[^'"]+shtml)
```

Comment: It also has a problem, for one example: `a = "http://finance.sina.com.cn/money/gold/AUTD/quote.shtml',name: '黄金',symbol: 'hf_AUTD',type: 'hf' },\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{ link: 'http://finance.sina.com.cn/money/gold/AGTD/quote.shtml'"  b = re.findall('(https?://finance\.sina\.com\.cn/[^"]+shtml)', a) print(b)`, , it still has wrong.

Comment: @littlely I wasn't sure if you might have href with single quotes as well. See my edit and [demo](https://rextester.com/OUJJ62077)